# How to configure ipython notebook on laptop to point to remote server for execution

Tags: ipython, pyspark, ipython-parallel

Well, my previous attempt to connect Pycharm from laptop to remote server did not see any ray of hope because of tcp/ip issues (which honestly I could not understand much and am still battling with) therefore I am looking to ipython as an alternative

Question: How can I configure ipython on laptop to point to the remote CentOS6 server for code processing and execution

Use Case: I want to use my laptop (using Win 7 Professional) to connect to the CentOS 6.4 master server using iPython.

Objective: To write the code in iPython on the laptop and then send the job to the server which will do the processing and should then return the result back to the laptop or to any other visualizing API.

The server and 3 namenodes already installed with pyspark and I have checked pyspark works in standalone mode on all four servers. Pyspark works in standalone mode on my laptop too.

Current setup: I use SSH to access the server. python 2.6 is installed on the server and the nodes. Able to run pyspark on all 4 servers in standalone mode

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the IPython Notebook server on one cluster-node and then connect to the cluster-node's url. To do this, you have to create a profile, where you may specify hostname, port and so on. Have a look at this:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html